# Como calcular variação percentual com 3 variáveis no R

Tags: r, dplyr

Eu tenho os seguintes dados:

```
library(sidrar)  
Tab1612SojaQde <-get_sidra(1612,variable = 214, period = c("last"=22), 
  geo="State",classific = 'c81', category = list(2713))

head(Tab1612SojaQde)
  Unidade da Federação (Código) Unidade da Federação Ano (Código)  Ano
2                            11             Rondônia         1996 1996
3                            11             Rondônia         1997 1997
4                            11             Rondônia         1998 1998
5                            11             Rondônia         1999 1999
6                            11             Rondônia         2000 2000
7                            11             Rondônia         2001 2001
  Variável (Código)             Variável
2               214 Quantidade produzida
3               214 Quantidade produzida
4               214 Quantidade produzida
5               214 Quantidade produzida
6               214 Quantidade produzida
7               214 Quantidade produzida
  Produto das lavouras temporárias (Código) Produto das lavouras temporárias
2                                      2713                   Soja (em grão)
3                                      2713                   Soja (em grão)
4                                      2713                   Soja (em grão)
5                                      2713                   Soja (em grão)
6                                      2713                   Soja (em grão)
7                                      2713                   Soja (em grão)
  Unidade de Medida (Código) Unidade de Medida Valor
2                       1017         Toneladas  1090
3                       1017         Toneladas  1296
4                       1017         Toneladas 15790
5                       1017         Toneladas 16100
6                       1017         Toneladas 36222
7                       1017         Toneladas 68687
```

Como calculo a variação do valor de um ano para o outro, por unidade da federação, pois aqui aparece somente o "Distrito Federal, mas são 11 estados.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isto com poucas linhas de código é através do pacote `dplyr`. Inclusive, recomendo dar uma estudada nele e no `tidyverse` se quiser aprender a manipular dados de maneira eficaz no `R`.

Creio que o código abaixo resolve os teus problemas:

```
Tab1612SojaQde %>%
  select(`Unidade da Federação`, Ano, Valor) %>%
  group_by(`Unidade da Federação`) %>%
  mutate(Difference = Valor - lag(Valor))
```

Vou descrever em itens o que cada comando acima faz:

- `%>%` é um comando do `R` chamado *pipe*. Ele está presente no pacote `dplyr`. O que ele faz é pegar o *output* de uma linha e utilizá-lo com *input* da linha seguinte
- `select` é outra função do `dplyr`. Com ela, estou selecionando apenas as colunas `Unidade da Federação`, `Ano` e `Valor`, pois me parece que as outras informações presentes neste conjunto de dados não são importantes neste momento. Este passo é opcional. Coloquei-o aqui porque, com menos colunas, conseguimos visualizar melhor o resultado obtido.
- `group_by` é mais uma função do `dplyr`. Com ela, eu informo ao `R` que ele deve agrupar os dados de acordo com uma coluna do conjunto de dados. Este agrupamento permitirá que apliquemos uma mesma função *k* vezes, em que *k* é o número de níveis da variável agrupada. Neste caso, serão as unidades da federação.
- por fim, a função `mutate`, também do `dplyr`, é utilizada junto com a função `lag` para calcular a variação ano a ano. Com `mutate`, eu crio uma nova coluna no meu conjunto de dados, chamada `Difference` (poderia ser qualquer outro nome). A função `lag` pega o resultado de `Valor[n]-Valor[n-1]`. Perceba, no resultado abaixo, que não existe variação para o ano 1996. Lógico, não existe valor para 1995, portanto não é possível saber qual foi a variação de 1995 para 1996.

  ```
  # A tibble: 594 x 4
  # Groups:   Unidade da Federação [27]
     `Unidade da Federação` Ano    Valor Difference
     <chr>                  <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>
   1 Rondônia               1996    1090         NA
   2 Rondônia               1997    1296        206
   3 Rondônia               1998   15790      14494
   4 Rondônia               1999   16100        310
   5 Rondônia               2000   36222      20122
   6 Rondônia               2001   68687      32465
   7 Rondônia               2002   83782      15095
   8 Rondônia               2003  126396      42614
   9 Rondônia               2004  163029      36633
  10 Rondônia               2005  233281      70252
  # ... with 584 more rows
  ```

Com este resultado da diferença bruta, é possível calcular a diferença percentual. Basta alterar um pequeno trecho do código acima, adaptando a fórmula da diferença:

```
Tab1612SojaQde %>%
  select(`Unidade da Federação`, Ano, Valor) %>%
  group_by(`Unidade da Federação`) %>%
  mutate(Difference = 100*(Valor - lag(Valor))/lag(Valor))

    # A tibble: 594 x 4
    # Groups:   Unidade da Federação [27]
       `Unidade da Federação` Ano    Valor Difference
       <chr>                  <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>
     1 Rondônia               1996    1090      NA   
     2 Rondônia               1997    1296      18.9 
     3 Rondônia               1998   15790    1118.  
     4 Rondônia               1999   16100       1.96
     5 Rondônia               2000   36222     125.  
     6 Rondônia               2001   68687      89.6 
     7 Rondônia               2002   83782      22.0 
     8 Rondônia               2003  126396      50.9 
     9 Rondônia               2004  163029      29.0 
    10 Rondônia               2005  233281      43.1 
    # ... with 584 more rows
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente @Marcus Nunes. Estou tentando aprender a manipular dados no R. Obrigado.

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.

Comment: Atenção: anteriormente a última linha do código era `mutate(Difference = 100*(Valor - lag(Valor))/Valor)`. Isto está **errado**. O código correto é `mutate(Difference = 100*(Valor - lag(Valor))/lag(Valor))`, como coloquei na atual edição do post.

Comment: Sim, eu fiz > mutate(Difference = (Valor/lag(Valor)-1)*100) deu certo tb